# How to run multiple servers with a python script?

Tags: python, wiremock

First of all I am a beginner.So pardon me if I am asking a dumb question.

I am trying to write a python automation code. With this code I should be able to run multiple programs like servers(mock backend api servers, C++ programs and java programs).

So what I thought is to make executables of C++ and JAVA programs and start them using python.

As the start what I did was, downloaded the [wiremock- standalone](http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/)  and tried to start the wiremock server with python.

Here I have tried following two at different times.

```
os.system("java -jar <wiremock_name>")
print(5)

subprocess.call("java -jar <wiremock_name>", shell=true)
print(5)
```

At both times, **the server was successfully deployed.But the print statement was not executed**.
I tried couple of threading scripts too. But same thing happened.

But it is the requirement(**start the server, then configure it using some curl commands**).

for me it looks like python is not coming back after it start the server. When we use the terminal we have to use the ctrl+C to manually end the process. I here server should also run.

**So what is happening here?**

**What should I do/follow to implement this functionality?**

Comment: The documentation for `subprocess.call` is clear: "Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete" and `os.system` similarly has you wait. You need to use a method that actually runs the process in the background, like `Popen`.

Comment: This doesn't solve your question but you can also shut down the WireMock server by sending a POST request to `/__admin/shutdown/`. API details here: http://wiremock.org/docs/api/#tag/System/paths/~1__admin~1shutdown/post . Might be useful once you get your problem resolved.

Comment: Thank you all, @Grismar I studied bit about it and tried it.It worked. And also what agoff says is also true. It is hard to find and kill  the server.